# can a function invoke another using a dot operator

Tags: c++, ns2

`Tcl::instance().eval(at->proc_);` instruction in ns2. can you please explain the concept of placing a dot operator between two functions as if i am not mistaken both `instance()` and `eval()` are functions and i have never come acress such concept in which one function invokes other by using a dot operator .

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess knowing nothing about `Tcl::instance`s:

`Tcl::instance` is a function that returns some object.  That object has a method called `eval`.  The programmer didn't see fit to name the returned object, and instead calls the method on the result directly.

```
struct Bar {
    Baz getBaz();
}

struct Foo {
    Bar getBar();
}

Foo foo = new Foo;

// the next two lines...
Bar bar = foo.getBar();
Baz baz = bar.getBaz();

// are exactly the same as this next line
baz = foo.getBar().getBaz();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Tcl` is a singleton and you obtain the current instance with the *static method* `instance`, which will return a reference to an object of type `Tcl`. *You access a static member of a class with `::`*. Then, you can call a method on such object, with the usual `.` notation.

That line is a shorthand for:

```
Tcl &tcl = Tcl::instance();
tcl.eval(at->proc_);
```

[Here](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node9.html) is a short reference for the `Tcl::instance` call:

> A single instance of the class is declared in ~tclcl/Tcl.cc as a static member variable; the programmer must obtain a reference to this instance to access other methods described in this section. The statement required to access this instance is:
>
> ```
>    Tcl& tcl = Tcl::instance();
> ```